# Stripe is not defined ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, stripe-payments

Anyone know how to fix this error Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: Stripe is not defined.
The step I am doing is to declare a Stripe variable that will stop the compiler from complaining about a missing object.

The code is below of my javascript file but anyway to fix the issue.Is my declare var Stripe causing the issue

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var Stripe: any;
 @Component({
selector: 'page-stripe-java-script',
templateUrl: 'stripe-java-script.html',
})

 export class StripeJavaScriptPage {

stripe = Stripe('YOUR_API_KEY');
card: any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
}

ionViewDidLoad() {
 this.setupStripe();
 }

setupStripe(){
let elements = this.stripe.elements();
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

this.card = elements.create('card', { style: style });

this.card.mount('#card-element');

this.card.addEventListener('change', event => {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  // this.stripe.createToken(this.card)
  this.stripe.createSource(this.card).then(result => {
    if (result.error) {
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
});
}
}
```

below is html code

```
          <ion-header>
          <ion-navbar>
 <ion-title></ion-title>
       </ion-navbar>

      </ion-header>
<ion-content>
```

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div id="card-element">
    <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
  </div>

  <!-- Used to display Element errors -->
  <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
</div>

<button ion-button block large>Add Card</button>

   </form>

   </ion-content>
```

Comment: Do you have <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script> included somewhere?

Comment: no do I place this in html or ts file

Comment: You can put it in your HTML <head>-tags.

Comment: Fixed the problem thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Using this in HEAD didn't work for me:**

```html
    <script src="js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

**But modifying it to this, resolves the issue for me:**

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me after upgrading to Vite5.2, had to import npm package